# Binary variable in a linear regression in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have a binary variable (biological sex) and I am concerned about the sign (positive or negative) of the estimate in my linear regression. In my `data.frame`, female is coded as 2 and male is coded as 1. I'm considering recoding it so that female is coded as 0 and male is coded as 1.

In either of these scenarios, how can I interpret the sign of the estimate? For example, if my outcome is height, I would expect a **positive** value if female is 0 and male is 1. But if female is 2 and male is 1, wouldn't I expect a **negative** value for an outcome of height?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Charlie

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programing as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your statement is correct. If you don't want to recode the variable just use `as.factor(sex)` in the formula itself. Then R knows that the value is not numeric and you don't have to worry about the coding of the variable.

Let me know if this helps or if you have further questions :)

Comment: brilliant thank you! that works perfectly

Comment: Thats nice :) Can you accept the awnser as the "best", so others who see this, and have the same problem, know that it worked?

Comment: gotchu, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Code sex as a categorical variable (class `factor`). R will then specify to which sex the value corresponds.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = data.frame(sex = factor(sample(c("female", "male"), size = 20, replace = TRUE)), 
               var = rnorm(20))
lm(var ~ sex, x)

# Call:
# lm(formula = var ~ sex, data = x)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)      sexmale  
#    -0.31066      0.08228
```

This means that in males, values in the variable `var` increase.